# What do we call a person whose guesses are almost always correct?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just wondering if there is a single word for a person who can always guess the correct answer.

Regards!

Comment: Maybe _oraculous_?

Comment: When you say always guess the correct answer, do you mean that person could just close his eyes and place his finger on one of the answers and that would be the correct one, or do you mean he can do an educated guess and he's almost always right?

Comment: @JohnHamilton the first one, I mean picks the correct answer by chance and there it is, the right answer!!

Comment: @RezaSaberi well, there really is no one-word for a fictional person who can pick correct answers by chance (as far as I know), so I doubt you'll find exactly what you're looking for if you insist on a one-word answer. Even Stan Lee's Lucky Man is just that, a lucky man.

Comment: "Omniscient" is most certainly the correct answer.

Comment: A "hunch"back hahaha

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say they were ***intuitive***; or ***had a good intuitive sense***.

It is OED sense 3 of ***intuitive***, which I particularly have in mind.

> 3. a. Of knowledge or mental perception: That consists in immediate apprehension, without the intervention of any reasoning process.
>
> 1645   J. Howell Epistolæ Ho-elianæ i. xxxix. 78   Being faithfull
>   ey-witnesses of those things which other receive but in trust,
>   wherunto they must yeeld an intuitive consent, and a kind of implicit
>   faith.
>
> 1690   J. Locke Ess. Humane Understanding iv. xi. 263   Intuitive
>   Knowledge, where the Ideas themselves, by an immediate view, discover
>   their Agreement, or Disagreement one with another.
>
> 1698   J. Norris Pract. Disc. Divine Subj. IV. 234   Intuitive
>   [Intellectual Sight] when we perceive the Agreement or Disagreement of
>   one Idea with another immediately and by themselves, without the
>   Mediation of any other Idea.
>
> 1704   J. Norris Ess. Ideal World II. iii. 146   Immediate knowledge,
>   or knowledge of the principle, we may call intuitive, because the mind
>   then in one and the same view that it perceives the ideas, perceives
>   also their relations.
>
> 1849   F. W. Robertson Serm. 1st Ser. i. 9   The intuitive vision
>   comes like an inspiration.
>
> ```
> b. Of a truth: Apprehended immediately or by intuition.
> ```
>
> 1833   J. S. Mill Let. 5 July (1910) i. ii. 54,   I conceive that most
>   of the highest truths are..intuitive; that is, they need neither
>   explanation nor proof, but if not known before are assented to as soon
>   as stated.
>
> 1872   W. Bagehot Physics & Polit. (1876) 118   The truths of
>   Arithmetic, intuitive or not, certainly cannot be acquired
>   independently of experience.
>
> c. Of any faculty or gift: Not acquired by learning; innate.
>
> 1621   R. Montagu Diatribæ Hist. Tithes Introd. 32   Hauing not the
>   gift of Prophesie, nor Intuitiue knowledge of what you would one day
>   vndertake.
>
> 1845   E. Holmes Life Mozart 9   The musical faculty appears to have
>   been intuitive in him.

Answer (score 6):

If they are simply guessing rather than deducing the answers, perhaps **lucky** or one of its synonyms - of which **jammy** is my favourite.

> 1 fortunate, successful, favoured.
>   *I consider myself the luckiest man on the face of the earth.*
>   fortunate.
>   *He has had a very fortunate life.
>   successful.*
>   *The successful candidate will be announced in June.*
>   favoured.
>   *They think of us as favoured beings.*
>   charmed.
>   blessed.
>   *He's the son of a doctor, and well blessed with money.*
>   prosperous.
>   *He has developed a prosperous business.*
>   jammy.
>   (British slang).
>   *He is seen as lucky. Dead jammy, in fact.
>   serendipitous.*
>   *It appears to have been a serendipitous discovery made around the year 200.*
>   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/lucky

Comment: Eventually this becomes "annoying" ^_^

Comment: I like "jammy" too.  It might be notable that usage is almost always in conjunction with "bastard", i.e "you jammy bastard!"

Answer (score 5):

**prophetic**
prəˈfɛtɪk/
adjective
1. accurately predicting what will happen in the future.
"his warnings proved prophetic"

Comment: Predicting is not the same as guessing.

Answer (score 2):

One word which has been popularized lately is [**superforecasters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superforecasting). It does not exactly describe people who are *always* correct, but rather people who are very good at considering different sources of evidence and quantifying the uncertainty of their judgements properly.

*He was very good at predicting the future. He was truly a **superforecaster**.*

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the future: a "clairvoyant".
When referring to other people's thoughts: a "telepath".
In a mystical context: a "diviner".
One who guesses new events and their outcome: a "prescient".

The Catholic Pope is deemed to be "infallible". He doesn't make mistakes when exercising his apostolic functions.

… generally, when one consistently guesses the right answer, I suppose we could describe him as a "far-sighted" person — but this last term downplays "luck".